# Is it safe to store Encryption Key in defaultConfiguration?

Tags: ios, swift, security, realm, keychain

My Realm db is encrypted. encryptionKey is stored in Keychain. What is safer way to manage this key?

Currently I'm calling method who sets up defaultConfiguration (schemaVersion, migrationBlock, fileURL, etc and encryptionKey as well) from `application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`, before any Realms will be instantiated. Later, Realms are instantiated with this defaultConfiguration throughout the app.
Like that:

```
// AppDelegate
   var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
   config.schemaVersion = 5
   config.migrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in ... }
   config.encryptionKey = KeychainManager.getRealmEncryptionKey()
   Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

// Somewhere else, later
   Realm()
```

Is it safe to put encryptionKey into defaultConfiguration? Where is defaultConfiguration stored at runtime and how easy will it be to extrude key from it?

Or preferable way will be to request encryptionKey from Keychain on every Realm instantiation and put it into custom Configuration which will present in memory only during Realm instance's life? Like this:

```
// AppDelegate
   var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
   config.schemaVersion = 5
   config.migrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in ... }
   Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

// Somewhere else, later
   var configTemp = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
   configTemp.encryptionKey = KeychainManager.getRealmEncryptionKey()
   Realm(configuration: configTemp)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to put encryptionKey into defaultConfiguration? Where is defaultConfiguration stored at runtime and how easy will it be to extrude key from it?

The key is stored in memory in the Realm configuration. If you're wondering how likely it is for a separate process to break out of the iOS Sandbox, inspect the memory of your app and extract the key from that... let's just say this would be an exploit of the OS of the highest degree and Apple would have a PR disaster on their hands.

So really, you should do what's most convenient for you. As long as you're not persisting the encryption key in plaintext on disk, you'll be as safe as you practically can be.